# Prove: $\frac{2x^2+xy}{(y+\sqrt{zx}+z)^2}+\frac{2y^2+yz}{(z+\sqrt{xy}+x)^2}+\frac{2z^2+zx}{(x+\sqrt{yz}+y)^2}\ge1$

Tags: inequality

Prove:
$$\frac{2x^2+xy}{(y+\sqrt{zx}+z)^2}+\frac{2y^2+yz}{(z+\sqrt{xy}+x)^2}+\frac{2z^2+zx}{(x+\sqrt{yz}+y)^2}\ge1$$ ($x,y,z>0$)

Comment: Schwarz, Chebyshev :(

Comment: Just like that, without any manipulation to the main statement?

Comment: I don'know how to ...

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ all non-negative, or just real numbers?

Comment: @YiyuanLee That doesn't matter actually, if one of them is negative, then the denominator part in one of the left hand inequality will turn imaginery. So, they are positive.

Comment: @YiyuanLee So,either all of them are positive or all of them are negative,

Comment: @TĩnhThu Are you sure that the question is not missing any context?

Answer (score 6):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz,for each expression :

$\left ( y+\sqrt{xz}+z \right )^{2}\le \left ( y+x+x \right )\left ( y+z+\frac{z^{2}}{x} \right )=\dfrac{\left ( 2x^{2}+xy \right )\left ( xy+xz+z^{2} \right )}{x^{2}}$

We have,

$\dfrac{2x^2+xy}{(y+\sqrt{zx}+z)^2}+\dfrac{2y^2+yz}{(z+\sqrt{xy}+x)^2}+\dfrac{2z^2+zx}{(x+\sqrt{yz}+y)^2}\ge \sum_{cyclic} \dfrac{x^{2}}{xy+xz+z^{2}}$

and again using Cauchy-Schwarz :

$\sum_{cyclic} \dfrac{x^2}{xy+xz+z^2}\ge \dfrac{(x+y+z)^2}{2(xy+yz+zx)+x^2+y^2+z^2}=\dfrac{(x+y+z)^2}{(x+y+z)^2}=1$. Q.E.D.